# Color for progress bar in gold badges on desktop

Tags: feature-request

The gold badge progress bar is *barely* visible in the desktop page. Could we have something more clear like in the mobile app?

Thanks for the consideration.

this is how it actually looks in desktop

[image: desktop]

this is how it is in mobile

[image: mobile]